# SQLite NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I make this exclude the row if any of the (stage1_choice, stage2_choice or stage3_choice) values = null ?

[image]

I've tried:

```
SELECT  r.breakout_id ,
        r.case_id ,
        r.stage_id ,
        r.chart_id ,
        s.stage1_choice ,
        s.stage2_choice ,
        s.stage3_choice
FROM    Results AS r ,
        Submissions AS s
WHERE   r.breakout_id = '1'
        AND s.breakout_id = '1'
        AND r.case_id = s.case_id
        AND stage_id < 4
        AND s.stage1_choice NOT NULL
        AND s.stage2_choice NOT NULL
        AND s.stage3_choice NOT NULL
```

But it still returns rows that contain a null in one of the columns.

Comment: What values are in the table when you say it is "NULL"? Do you mean it is an SQL NULL, or is it an empty string? And don't you mean, IS NOT NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT r.breakout_id, r.case_id, r.stage_id, r.chart_id, s.stage1_choice, s.stage2_choice, s.stage3_choice
FROM Results as r, Submissions as s 
WHERE r.breakout_id = '1' AND s.breakout_id = '1' AND r.case_id = s.case_id AND stage_id < 4 AND s.stage1_choice NOT NULL AND s.stage2_choice IS NOT NULL AND s.stage3_choice IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
SELECT r.breakout_id, r.case_id, r.stage_id, r.chart_id, s.stage1_choice,   s.stage2_choice, s.stage3_choice
FROM Results as r, Submissions as s 
WHERE r.breakout_id = '1' AND s.breakout_id = '1' AND r.case_id = s.case_id AND stage_id < 4 AND s.stage1_choice != '' AND s.stage2_choice != '' AND s.stage3_choice != ''
```

Comment: Still returns rows that contain a NULL in one of the three stageX_choice columns :s

Comment: Actually, !='' seems to work for me! Why would that work and not IS NOT NULL?

Comment: @tctc91 I'm not sure, it may be the type of data or the database engine

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for not null is different, and it's `IS NOT NULL`

```
AND s.stage1_choice IS NOT NULL 
AND s.stage2_choice IS NOT NULL 
AND s.stage3_choice IS NOT NULL
```

From documentation

> - To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators

Learn more [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: Still returns rows that contain a NULL in one of the three stageX_choice columns.